# Redirect from /profile to /profile/edit [FOSUserBundle]

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I want to redirect people from /profile to /profile/edit and I was trying like that in routing.yml:

```
another_route:
    path: /profile
    defaults:
        _controller: FOSUserBundle:Profile:edit
        route: fos_user_profile_edit
        permanent: true
```

but well, that doesn't work ( it still gets to the /profile page with the content from this site ). From what I read on Symfony's page it should work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your redirect won't work if you're importing `FOSUserBundle` routes before your *custom* route rule and, of course, routes are matched subsequently and the parsing is stopped upon first match.

You have a problem also in your `another_route`: even if you move it - without any modification - that won't work because you're passing the wrong controller value

So you have to modify the `_controller` value (as follows) and place that route before `FOSUserBundle` import ones

```
another_route:
    path: /profile
    defaults:
        _controller: FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect
        route: fos_user_profile_edit
        permanent: true
```